# Haskell GUI: how much can be done with Haskell?

Tags: libraries, gui, haskell

I've been wanting to try out graphics in Haskell. From what I've seen, the available libraries are either front-ends to C/C++ libraries, or an abstraction of them with minimal features. The high-level libraries do not seem to suit my needs, and so I'm left with lower-level front-ends.

**What I need is to render tiles and text** - basics for a very simple game. I know how to do this with C, and was thinking I could write the graphics in C and interface it with Haskell. The alternative is to write the graphics using a Haskell library.

**My question is, can available Haskell libraries achieve what I want?** I do not want to bend over backwards; if C can do it better than I would like to know.

Comment: How much *should* be done is unanswerable if you don't tell us what you need be done. How much *could* be done is a different question, one that might even be on topic.

Comment: Hi Pubby8, if you can update your question with what exactly you're trying to do that's got you thinking about this, feel free to flag it for reopening.

Comment: Why not use SDL? It's low-level (for Haskell), yes, but I don't think that writing graphics in C would give you considerable benefits.

Answer (score 8):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is an excellent library with [good Haskell bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL)—and related libraries for [images](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-image), [audio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-mixer), and [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-ttf)—for which enough [tutorials](http://www.animal-machine.com/blog/2010/04/getting-started-with-sdl-in-haskell/) exist to get you off the ground; being rather low-level, it requires a bit of care to keep things pretty and functional, but in my experience SDL and Haskell make a superb combination.

Comment: I've used SDL before as a C library. How similar is the Haskell version to the C one?

Comment: @Pubby8: They’re quite similar. All the Haskell version really does is explicate where `IO` is happening.

Comment: +1, I second this recommendation. I'm using SDL with Haskell to code a small 2D game, so far with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if there is a good C/C++ alternative to haskell that does GUI well, then look no further:
http://qt-project.org/

Definitely the strongest GUI framework out there for C++.

If however, your question was "find me something better in haskell" then I can't help you :/